# Gmock parameterized tests running twice

Tags: c++, googletest, googlemock

Here is an example code:

```
struct MyFixture: public ::testing::Test
{
};

template <typename param>
struct MyFixtureWithParam: public MyFixture, public ::testing::WithParamInterface<param>
{
};

using MyFixtureWithNumber = MyFixtureWithParam<int>;

TEST_P(MyFixtureWithNumber, Test1)
{
    std::cout << "Test1 with param: " << GetParam() << std::endl;
}

INSTANTIATE_TEST_CASE_P(Test1, MyFixtureWithNumber, ::testing::Values(0,3));

TEST_P(MyFixtureWithNumber, Test2)
{
    std::cout << "Test2 with param: " << GetParam() << std::endl;
}

INSTANTIATE_TEST_CASE_P(Test2, MyFixtureWithNumber, ::testing::Values(5, 7));
```

I expect to get 4 test (2 instances for Test1 and 2 instances for Test2), but 8 tests is run. Why? How to fix that?

Answer (score 2):

```
INSTANTIATE_TEST_CASE_P(prefix, fixture, generator)
```

registers tests to be run for *every* parameterized test case which uses the same `fixture` type.  The `prefix` is only used in building names for the parameterized tests, which appear in output and can be used with a `--gtest-filter` command-line argument.

So if you want `Test1` and `Test2` to run with different sets of parameter values, you'll need to force them to be different fixture types:

```
// ...

struct MyFixtureForTest1 : public MyFixtureWithNumber {};
struct MyFixtureForTest2 : public MyFixtureWithNumber {};

TEST_P(MyFixtureForTest1, Test1)
{
    std::cout << "Test1 with param: " << GetParam() << std::endl;
}

INSTANTIATE_TEST_CASE_P(SmallValues, MyFixtureForTest1, ::testing::Values(0,3));

TEST_P(MyFixtureForTest2, Test2)
{
    std::cout << "Test2 with param: " << GetParam() << std::endl;
}

INSTANTIATE_TEST_CASE_P(LargeValues, MyFixtureForTest2, ::testing::Values(5, 7));
```

Comment: For a little more brevity, you can do: ```using MyFixtureForTest1 = MyFixtureWithNumber; using MyFixtureForTest2 = MyFixtureWithNumber```

Comment: @Rehan Yes, it looks like Google Test considers the fixture part unique per spelling of that macro argument, not just by C++ type identity.